# MYSQL Error Importing Database

Tags: mysql

This is a first for me... I'm importing into an database with no tables from a working backup.

```
Error
SQL query:


--
-- Dumping data for table `exp_accessories`
--

INSERT INTO `exp_accessories` (`accessory_id`, `class`, `member_groups`, `controllers`, `accessory_version`) VALUES
(1, 'Expressionengine_info_acc', '1|5', 'addons|addons_accessories|addons_extensions|addons_fieldtypes|addons_modules|addons_plugins|admin_content|admin_system|content|content_edit|content_files|content_files_modal|content_publish|design|homepage|members|myaccount|tools|tools_communicate|tools_data|tools_logs|tools_utilities', '1.0'),
(2, 'Developer_acc', '1|5', 'addons|addons_accessories|addons_extensions|addons_fieldtypes|addons_modules|addons_plugins|admin_content|admin_system|content|content_edit|content_files|content_files_modal|content_publish|design|homepage|members|myaccount|tools|tools_communicate|tools_data|tools_logs|tools_utilities', '1.7.1'),
(3, 'Devotee_acc', '1|5', 'addons|addons_accessories|addons_extensions|addons_fieldtypes|addons_modules|addons_plugins|admin_content|admin_system|content|content_edit|co[...]
MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Answer (score 1):

what does your create table code look like?
this?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `exp_accessories`;    
CREATE TABLE `exp_accessories` (
      `accessory_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `class` varchar(75) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `member_groups` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'all',
      `controllers` text,
      `accessory_version` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`accessory_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

does it include an auto increment value?
run a query on the table and see if anything is in there?
also try `DESCRIBE exp_accessories`

if you restarted the import at any time, the inserts may have already ran.
see if your dump file also includes the `DROP TABLE` call.
What DB admin tool are you using to run the import?

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin and just running it through the tool. It runs fine through another hosting provider, so I think it's localhost issues that I'm having.